# Nginx вместо Apache

Tags: apache, nginx

Планирую создать сеть из нескольких выделенных серверов с apache2 и сервера балансировщика с nginx, который плюс к этому при обращении типа /files/s??/* будет выдавать статику с соответствующего сервера. На машинах с apache2 будет стоять PHP (для основной логики), Redis (в качестве DB для активно используемых данных) и MySQL для долгосрочного хранения всех данных. (Данные на сайте будут меняться пользователями относительно часто). Недавно попалась статья про установку php на nginx (в виде FastCGI). Сейчас думаю, стоит ли вообще на бекэндах использовать apache2 (на apache2 стоит в качестве модуля)?

Answer (score 2):

Если кроме mod_php на apache ничего не планируется использовать, то можно смело от него отказываться в пользу [php fpm](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).

Answer (score 2):

php fpm - вполне вариант, тока сильно зависит от направления, чем будет сервер. Если шаред хостинг, то под какой панелью? phpfpm не везде работает или руками пилить надо.. Да и nginx не на всех панелях поддерживается (Cpanel, ISP, DirectAdmin?). Если руками все делать и попотеть - можно и к чистому nginx php прикрутить.

в конфигах nginx спокойно делится по расширению, какой файл кем будет обрабатываться. На nginx- статику(картинки, zip и прочее), а .htaccess и php пусть апач обрабатывает